# Large number of tables and Hibernate memory consumption

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, memory

I'm working on a large ERP project which has database model with about 2100 tables. With "only" 500 tables mapped with Hibernate, application deployed on the web server takes about 3GB of working memory.

Is there any way to reduce Hibernate's metamodel memory footprint when using that many tables in one persistence unit? Or should I just give up on ORMs and go with plain old JDBC (or even [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org))?

Right now I'm using Hibernate 4.1.8, Spring 3.1.3, JBoss AS 7.1 and working with MSSQL database.

Edit:

[JavaMelody memory histogram output](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=cYr9ttTN) - with 2000 generated test tables that are a bit smaller in scope from the original db model (hence 'only' 1.3GB of spent memory)

Edit 2:

Java MAT heap analysis:

- [Leak Suspects](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0BxIzMpeayz9nOERlbmlYQ0pkNzA)
- [Top Consumers](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0BxIzMpeayz9nN0E1emJjSnJZOW8)

Comment: Do you know how much of the 3GB are consumed by hibernate?

Comment: Considering that with ~10 tables memory consumed is less than 256MB, I'd reckon its north of 2.74 GB :)

Comment: Would you like to give Batoo JPA a shot. http://batoo.jp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encountre the same problem, and i successfully reduce the memory consumtion from xGB to 30M, the buildSessionFactory pass from 2min to 7 secondes.

An important part of solution is posted here

[postInstantiate buildSessionFactory slow/memory huge database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23867296/postinstantiate-buildsessionfactory-slow-memory-huge-database/23870757#23870757)

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest to do profiling of application in production or staging using [java melody](https://code.google.com/p/javamelody/) to find out where or who is consuming maximum memory and based on profiling result you should decide on what changes should be done in application.

Java melody is very easy to integrate and configure and in production you can enable or disable by just updating web.xml

Comment: Going to try to do that and update the question with the results tomorrow, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Added the memory histogram from JavaMelody.

Comment: not able to make out much from histogram, but you should look for which of your classes consuming maximum memory and then check who is holding them. not sure it should easy to find out memory usage and its bottleneck easy.

Comment: Yes, and the problem is where I initially assumed it is. Added MAT outputs for reference.

Comment: from memory consumption i think most of memory is being hold by session factory, are you using any cache? or loading lot of objects in persistence context?

Comment: There's no 2nd level cache, this is memory consumed upon application initialization with nothing else than JPA entities in it.

Answer (score 5):

An open hibernate session will tend to accrue objects as it is in use. This is not a memory leak; a hibernate session is designed to be used once for a request, and it caches objects that are persistent (i.e. live within the session), as well as queries and other data. If you call `session.toString()`, you will see a laundry list of objects that live in the session.

If you work with a very large number of objects, consider handling the objects in batches. You can call `session.clear()` after each batch to evict cached data and persistent objects from the session and reduce the session's memory footprint (sometimes dramatically).

After calling `session.clear()`, be aware that objects loaded before this call will revert to the *detached* state, and are no longer active for the current session.

You can also use *lazy fetching* to optimize the amount of data that hibernate has to load in order to handle a given operation. You can read more about this in the hibernate documentation. I would recommend enabling hibernate's SQL logging feature, and checking to see whether hibernate is pulling back data that it doesn't need.

You can also configure hibernate to gather statistics that can help you:

```
sessionFactory.getStatistics().setStatisticsEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

What is the purpose for your hibernate object, hibernate is only suitable for CURD (Create, update, read, delete), but unsuitable for caculation. for any caculation purpose (specially cross table), using store procedure and ibatis together is better.

Comment: The project requirement is multiple RDBMS targeting (i.e. Oracle, PGSQL, MSSQL, MySQL...) which sadly makes ibatis a very (VERY!) expensive option. Also, I very much disagree that Hibernate is only suitable for CRUD operations.